# swift3: Identificación única de periferico BLE

Tags: swift3, bluetooth

Esta es la idea, mi app se conecta con un dispositivo externo a través de BLE (bluetooth low energy) usando la api nativa Core Bluetooth. Una vez que se conecta entra en acción un procedimiento cuyo objetivo es comparar la mac de este dispositivo con una base de datos. Si existe en la base el dispositivo se puede usar, sino, se bloquea el uso de este dispositivo

Todo esto sirve perfectamente en la versión Android de mi app.

```
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
{
    dispositivosDisponibles.add(device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress());
}
```

Sin embargo en la versión iOS no se puede leer la MAC pues esto es una propiedad privada y fue desactivada desde la versión 7. Ante esto:

1. He buscado en foros y recomiendan usar la propiedad `identifier` del `CBPeripheral`. Sin embargo esta cambia segun la documentación oficial al menos cada 15 minutos, en la practica cambia una vez al día (no tengo seguro que esto sea regla general).
2. He explorado las características y servicios del dispositivo externo pero en ninguna encuentro la MAC deseada y dado que es un dispositvo externo no puedo manipular el framework para agregar este dato a la pila de información publica.

Alguien me puede ayudar con alguna idea de como identificar de manera única y permanente un dispositivo. No tiene por que se necesariamente la MAC, alguna otra api para la conexión bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede utilizar el identificador del dispositivo:

```
let UUIDValue = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```